# Sending Data over UDP to Windows Server Socket

Tags: python, windows, sockets

I am trying to send UDP packets to a socket on a Windows 64-bit machine. On the server side, an application is running which created the socket using socket() API of Windows and then binds to a specific port.

Socket was created on server side as: socket(2, 2, 0). So, the socket type is UDP.

I am using Python on the client side to communicate with it. However, I am not getting the desired response. I need to send the following 3 DWORDs in the format: `DWORD1 + DWORD2 + DWORD3`

```
DWORD1 = 0xAABBCCDD
DWORD2 = 0x0
DWORD3 = 0x1
```

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import socket
import time

ip_addr = '192.168.2.6'
port = 1234

addr = (ip_addr, port)

buffer = '\xdd\xcc\xbb\xaa' + '\x00\x00\x00\x00' + '\x01\x00\x00\00'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect((ip_addr, port))

s.sendto(buffer, addr)

data, server = s.recvfrom(1024)

print data
```

Do I need to send the UDP packets using little endian or big endian? The server side is a 64-bit Windows machine.

Comment: The difference in little or big endian, is controlled by your application - not necessarily the network layer of the operating system. Also, how do you setup the socket in Windows? You keep talking about a "windows server socket", that isn't typically a thing. Windows doesn't creates sockets out of nowhere, an application does? So what program are you trying to communicate with? I suggest you do `struct.pack('B', 0)` and `struct.pack('>I', 2864434397)`, that way it's easier for you to change the endian.

Comment: Windows is little endian, and you have windows on both ends.

Comment: @Torxed: I have edited the question to make it more clear. There's a 64-bit application running on the other windows machine which has created a socket using Windows APIs like socket() and then it binds to it. It's a UDP socket and then it binds to port 1234 on server side. All I want to know is, am I sending the data correctly from the client side or not? Unfortunately, I don't have source code for server side application which has created the socket. But I have details of the socket.

Comment: It really depends on what that closed source application wants. Yes you are sending data correctly. But the question is, is it the correct data expected by the other software? Windows or the API used to create the socket doesn't have anything to do with how the data is parsed or expected to be parsed.